# Thinking of getting Pandemic...should I buy one or both of the expansion packs along with the base game?

Tags: pandemic

I enjoy games and puzzles, although I don't have many people to play with (usually 2 players, sometimes 3). I've heard that Pandemic is a good solo game so I'm especially interested in it. I'm thinking of just purchasing the base game and later getting the expansions if we like it but I've seen extremely positive reviews of the expansions so it may be worth getting them too.

Answer (score 0):

Never played Pandemic solo so I've been hesitating waiting for a better answer, but as you have none...

I'd get the base game; you can always add later if you really enjoy it solo. Pandemic's base game is good anyway - it's not a game that *needs* its expansions.

If you're thinking of buying the set to save on future postage, then that's your call ;-)  It would not be a bad decision to do so.

Do buy the latest edition so any expansions you buy later match artistically.

'The Brink' expansion's main feature is to be able to play with 5/6 players, less relevant to you, though you do need it for 'In The Lab' (which I've not played, so I'll stop there :-)